# zabbix_sender: send value error: ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out

Tags: zabbix

I have some problems sending my test data to Zabbix Server.

My configurations are set up, even have Zabbix agent installed and correctly working (sends data for monitoring CPU, memory,...).

This is the situation: I have a Zabbix installed on a Debian VM, and configured a host with correct IP, port, item(Zabbix trapper).
I want to send a value just for testing from my Windows 10 PC using "zabbix_sender"; later I want to find a way to get data from a .txt file for monitoring.

Used command from my cmd:

zabbix_sender -vv -z XXX.XXX.X.X -p XXXX -s "IT-CONS-PC4" -k trap -o "test"

Error:

zabbix_sender [8688]: DEBUG: send value error: ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out

Did someone else had this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This errors out on the network level.

- check that the local firewall on the Zabbix server allows incoming connections on the server port (10051 by default)
- check that the VM network connectivity is correct

As a simple test, you can telnet from the box with zabbix_sender to the Zabbix server on port 10051. If that fails, you have a basic network issue.

Comment: My Zabbix server is set on port 8080. Is port 10051 mandatory? My PC is set on 10050. Both ports are opened in firewall and also forwarded.

Comment: 3176:20161013:171745.621 agent #0 started [main process]
  9116:20161013:171745.625 agent #1 started [collector]
  6076:20161013:171745.629 agent #2 started [listener #1]
 10780:20161013:171745.633 agent #3 started [listener #2]
  8064:20161013:171745.637 agent #4 started [listener #3]
 10748:20161013:171745.642 agent #5 started [active checks #1]
 10748:20161013:171748.663 active check configuration update from [xx.xx.xx.xx:8080] started to fail (ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out)

Comment: I've forgot to say that I tried with telnet and it works. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Please  show _exact_ commands used for zabbix_sender and telnet. Also, why is your agent configured to connect to port 8080?

Comment: zabbix_sender -vv -z XXX.XXX.X.X -p XXXX -s "IT-CONS-PC4" -k trap -o "test"

Comment: telnet IP Port - for testing telnet

Comment: My agent is configured to connect to port 8080 because Zabbix server is installed on a virtual machine having the 8080 port forwarded.

Comment: Those are not exact commands, as the IP address and port are obfuscated. Apparently your port forwarding is not working properly, or there is a firewall, blocking that port.

Answer (score 1):

after many an hour, this is what fixed it.

Active Agent Checks were failing with following error or similar:
active check configuration update from [zabbix.verticalcomputers.com:10051] started to fail (ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out)
For whatever reason, active agents wont be able to connect properly (active checks won't work, only passive), if server is behind a firewall NAT'd, and you don't have the following in your ifcfg-eth0 (or whatever NIC) file. It will work if you bypass the firewall and put a public IP right on the zabbix server.
  NM_CONTROLLED=no
  BOOTPROTO=static

If you use the CentOS 7 wizard, or nmtui to config your NIC, instead of manually, those lines don't get added.
I noticed this because when running "ip add", I'd get the following:

2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:15:5d:07:82:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.32.2.25/24 brd 10.32.2.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Notice the "noprefixroute". That was unsettling, so I dug for a long time online, with no leads. After adding the two lines to the NIC config mentioned above, and restarting the network, now looks like this:
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:15:5d:07:82:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.32.2.25/24 brd 10.32.2.255 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 2021, and I hit the same snag right now

Answer (score 1):

Late but i hope this could help you.

Check the last sections of [scripts docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/scripts)

1. Be sure that your zabbix server has **connection** with your zabbix agent (normally cause by firewalls)
   1.1 by port **10050** for passive checks
   1.2 by port **10051** for active checks

```sh
# you can do it with telnet from your zabbix server
> telnet <agent ip> <10050 or 10051>
    Trying <agent ip>...
    Connected to <agent ip>.
    Escape character is '^]'.
```

2. You can modify your [server/agent config file](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd) to increase `Timeout` directive. By default is `3` and you can set it up to `30` seconds. If you do this, be sure to modify in both server and agent.
   2.1 Don't forget restarting the services `service zabbix-agent restart` and `service zabbix-server restart`